# Child route not found when redirected to, but works okay otherwise

Tags: javascript, routes, aurelia

I am having an issue with child routers/routes. (Abbreviated example below.)

**app.ts**

```
config.map([
    { route: "auth", name: "auth", moduleId: "auth" }
]);
```

**auth/index.ts**

```
config.map([
    { route: "", redirect: "login" },
    { route: "login", name: "login", moduleId: "./login", title: "Login" }
]);
```

**authentication-step.ts**

```
run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.auth)) {
        if (!this.authContext.isAuthenticated())
            return next.cancel(this.router.navigateToRoute('auth/login', { return: true }));
    }

    return next();
}
```

If a secured route is requested, I have an `AuthenticationStep` which will redirect to `auth/login`. This does not work, for instance, if I try to go to a secured route (e.g. `admin/something`) I get the error below. However, if I navigate directly to `auth/login`, the login page shows up correctly.

> A route with name 'auth/login' could not be found.

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty route with a redirect to your child router's configuration:

```
{ route: '', redirect: 'login' }
```

Then, change your call to `navigateToRoute` to navigate to `auth`.

```
run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.auth)) {
        if (!this.authContext.isAuthenticated())
            return next.cancel(this.router.navigateToRoute('auth', { return: true }));
    }

    return next();
}
```

Comment: I do have a redirect route in place already, sorry I didn't include it in the example. I don't want to navigate to just `auth`, because I want to know why it's not working to redirect to `auth/login` directly like this. Thanks!

Comment: (I did put this fix in temporarily, and it works. Still want to know _why_, though.)

Comment: The reason you can't navigate using the main app router to 'auth/login' is because that route doesn't exist on the app router. There are probably other ways to accomplish this, but the way i gave is the simplest.

Comment: I thought the route you're navigating too was split on `/`, so first it would find the `auth` route in the outermost router (`app.ts`), then that route points to `auth/index.ts` and it would find the `login` route there. I mean, this works fine if I enter `#/auth/login` directly, just not when redirecting...

Comment: Yeah, when you tell a router to do navigation it can only route to routes it knows about. A parent router doesn't really "know" about any child router's routes.

Comment: Another way to accomplish this is using `config.mapUnkownRoutes` and returning the login view. http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/6

Comment: Fabio, that would for some use cases, but I'm not sure it is the right approach here. I'm willing to be proven wrong though.